# How to make a list of data.frame with a loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I am pretty new to R and I try to make my first loop for my school work.

My problem is a try to make a list of data.frame (Each iteration give a data.frame) but just the first data.frame show in my list

Exemple of my code :

```
Attribution=function(x){
list_of_frame <- replicate(10, data.frame())
  N=1
  while (N < 10)     {
  TIGE <- read.xlsx("E:PlacetteparPlacette.xlsx", N, colNames=T)

  ( some code)

   list_of_frame[[N]] <- TableauPlacette

  return(list_of_frame)

  } 
   N=N+1
    }
```

Result:
[[1]] = First Data.frame
[[2]]
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
[[3]]
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
[[4]]
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

Sorry for my English is not my first language (I try my best ). I hope you understand my problem

Comment: Maybe just `myList <- lapply(1:9, function(N) read.xlsx("E:PlacetteparPlacette.xlsx", N, colNames=TRUE))`.

Comment: i will try this but if a understand, this code will make data.frame with each sheet of the  XLSX document ? I try to make list of data.frame whit the result finale of each iteration of the loops ( a call this result TableauPlacette in my code)

Comment: OK, then add the desired code into the `lapply` like `function(N) { read.xlsx(...); <more code>; TableauPlacette};`.

Comment: If you use a `for` loop you don't need to manage the index (your `N`) - with a loop `for (N in 1:9)` R will automatically start `N` at 1 and then change it to 2, 3, ..., 9 without you needing to to `N <- N+1` or anything like that. A `while` loop is best used in the unusual case where you don't know at the start how many iterations will be needed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to switch the N+1 and return statements around.  As written the function is returning after the first iteration.  Try this:

```
Attribution=function(x){
  list_of_frame <- replicate(10, data.frame())
  N=1
  while (N < 10)     {
    TIGE <- read.xlsx("E:PlacetteparPlacette.xlsx", N, colNames=T)

    ( some code)

    list_of_frame[[N]] <- TableauPlacette

    N<-N+1
  } 
  return(list_of_frame)
}
```